# How can I use Liquid / Jekyll to extract the date from an image's filename?

Tags: date, jekyll, filenames

I understand that Jekyll auto-extracts the date from a post's filename.

How to the same with an image's filename please?

Let's assume the following format of the image filenames:

- **2020-12-10**_A_the_rest_of_the_filename_of_the_image.jpg
- **2020-12-10**_B_the_rest_of_the_filename_of_the_image.jpg
- **2020-12-10**_C_the_rest_of_the_filename_of_the_image.jpg
- **2021-01-04**_A_the_rest_of_the_filename_of_the_image.jpg
- **2021-01-04**_B_the_rest_of_the_filename_of_the_image.jpg

Thus it only includes **YYYY-MM-DD** and then some further sorting/index information (such as a, b, c, ...), and then the rest of the image's filename.

The main goal is to be able to extract the date as follows:

- **10 Dec, 2020**
- **10 Dec, 2020**
- **10 Dec, 2020**
- **04 Jan, 2021**
- **04 Jan, 2021**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the date part out of you file name, you could either use the [`slice`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/slice/) or [`split`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/split/) filter.
If you do use the `split` filter, you will want to use the [`first`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/first/) filter, in order to take the first element of the created array.

To get the date format you want, you can just use the [`date`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/) filter.

1. With `slice`:

   ```
   {{ "2020-12-10_A_the_rest_of_the_filename_of_the_image.jpg" | slice: 0, 10 | date: "%d %b, %Y" }}
   ```
2. With `split`:

   ```
   {{ "2020-12-10_A_the_rest_of_the_filename_of_the_image.jpg" | split: "_" | first | date: "%d %b, %Y" }}
   ```

Those both results in: `10 Dec, 2020`

---

Additionally, you might want to read the Ruby documentation about the date format available at: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime